# por que mi app de flutter desktop nose abre ysolo muestra el proceso en el administrador de tareas

Tags: flutter

he estado creando una app de flutter desktop pero al momento de ejecutarla, solo muestra el proceso activo en el administrador de tareas pero no se ve ni muestra nada. porfa si alguien sabe como ayudarme agradecido!!